# Creating a random number between 1-100 that doesn't change everytime

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Im creating a little guess game in python google app engine and im trying to set the answer to be a random number between 1-100

which can be done by...

```
import random

#Sets the answer to a random integer between 1 and 100
answer = random.randint(1,100)
```

Which is fine. But I have the following code and every time the user guesses the answer it will be reset to a random number so i'm wondering which is the best way to have the number stored only once and then it will remain as that number.

```
class GuessGame(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #Sets user to the current user
        user = users.get_current_user()
        #Create logout URL for user
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.path)
        #If user is logged in do the following
        if user:
            #Tells jinja2 to use numberguess.html template
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('numberguess.html')
            #Sets the values to pass through to the template
            template_values = {
                'user': user.nickname(),
                'url_logout': logout_url,
                'url_logout_text': 'Log out',
            }
            #Sends those values to the template
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
        else:
            #If user isn't logged in then create the login url
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

    def post(self):
        #Sets user to the current user
        user = users.get_current_user()
        #Create logout URL for user
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.path)
        #If user is logged in do the following
        if user:
            #Tells jinja2 to use numberguess.html template
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('numberguess.html')
            #Gets the content from the form that has been sent via POST
            stguess = self.request.get('content')
            #Sets msg to a string
            msg = ''
            #Sets guess to minus 1 to begin with
            guess = -1
            try:
                #Sets guess to what was sent in the form only if its an int
                guess = int(stguess)
            except:
                #If not an int then set it to minus 1
                guess = -1
            #Sets the answer to a random integer between 1 and 100
            answer = random.randint(1,100)
            #If the guess is the same as the answer then set msg to correct
            if guess == answer:
                msg = 'Congrats! The guess is correct!'
            #If guess is less than 0 tell the user to provide positive number
            #This also works if user tries to input a string because of the try/except code
            elif guess < 0:
                msg = 'Please provide a positive number'
            #If guess too low then set msg
            elif guess < answer:
                msg = 'Your guess is too low'
            #If guess too high then set msg
            else:
                msg = 'Your guess is too high'
            #Sets the values to pass through to the template
            template_values = {
                'user': user.nickname(),
                'url_logout': logout_url,
                'url_logout_text': 'Log Out',
                'guess': stguess,
                'guess_text': msg,
            }
            #Sends those values to the template
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

Comment: Why don't you set the variable in the constructor? Which will prevent it from getting set again.

Comment: why you want to store the previous result if user guess is correct

Comment: @Nimi Where about's would I put this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the value in the [datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/).

This may need some polish but here is how I would do it:

```
class StoredRandomNumber(ndb.Model):
    User = ndb.StringProperty()
    answer = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    GuessNumber = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

in your post:

```
        randomEntity = StoredRandomNumber.query(StoredRandomNumber.User==str(user)).get()
        if randomEntity == None:
            randomEntity = StoredRandomNumber(User=str(user), answer=random.randint(1,100))


        if guess == randomEntity.answer:
            msg = 'Congrats! The guess is correct!'
            #re-seed for new game
            randomEntity.answer =random.randint(1,100)
            randomEntity.GuessNumber = 0
        elif guess < 0:
            msg = 'Please provide a positive number'
            randomEntity.GuessNumber +=1
        elif guess < randomEntity.answer:
            msg = 'Your guess is too low'
            randomEntity.GuessNumber +=1
        else:
            msg = 'Your guess is too high'
            randomEntity.GuessNumber +=1

        #Save the updates
        randomEntity.put()
```

Answer (score -1):

Provide a fixed seed before generating the random number. That'll cause the same sequence of numbers to be generated every time.

```
 import random
 random.seed(5)
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 42
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 28
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 25
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 1
 random.seed(5)
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 42
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 28
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 25
 random.randint(1,100)
=> 1
```

Comment: I see, but how can I get this to be a number between 1-100?

Comment: If you do it this way, anyone hitting the same instance will have the same number to guess. Whenever that number IS guessed, you will then re-create the random number, changing the actual answer for OTHER users on the same instance. Not really the type of solution here. In standard python that would work marvelously. Not on the App Engine unfortunately :(